# C printf specifier %lld prints characters "ld"

Tags: c, printf, gnu99

I am developing using gcc (-std=gnu99) for an embedded toolchain (Myriota), and I have problems with printf.

when I try the following code:

```
long long int time = TimeGet();
printf("\nSeconds since epoch: %lld\r\n", time);
```

it prints:

```
Seconds since epoch: ld
```

Using `"%" PRId64` prints the same "ld".

Any ideas? I'd appreciate if you could point me to the right place.

**Edit**
variable type corrected `long long int time`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you were right to point out that the type was incorrect. It was a long long int. I suspected this to be a bug, but I needed a sanity check. I'll contact Myriota.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, your C library, specifically its implementation of `printf`, doesn't support C99.

The type `long long int` and the `%lld` format were introduced by the 1999 ISO C standard (C99). Using `gcc -std=c99` makes the compiler attempt to conform to C99, (or `-std=cNN` for later editions) but it can't make the runtime library do things that it doesn't implement. You have a mismatch between what the compiler supports and what the runtime library supports.

In C90, calling `printf` with `%lld` in the format string had undefined behavior.

Does `%ld` work for an argument of type `long int`? If the argument is in the range `LONG_MIN` to `LONG_MAX`, converting and using `%ld` might be a good workaround. If you need to print values less than `LONG_MIN` or greater than `LONG_MAX`, implementing a `long long int` to string conversion isn't horribly difficult. (And in some implementations, `long int` and `long long int` are both 64 bits, so just converting to `long int` and using `%ld` is sufficient.)

Answer (score 1):

The Myriota SDK uses newlib-nano which does not support int64_t. 
I'll have to implement my own function to convert to char string, or cast to uint32_t.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void int64_to_string(int64_t num, char* str) {
    if (num < 0) {
        *str++ = '-';
        num = -num;
    }

    char buffer[20]; // Maximum 19 digits in int64_t
    int i = 0;
    do {
        buffer[i++] = num % 10 + '0';
        num /= 10;
    } while (num != 0);

    while (i > 0) {
        *str++ = buffer[--i];
    }
    *str = '\0';
}
```

```
int64_t num = 1234567890123456789;
char str[20]; // Maximum 19 digits in int64_t
int64_to_string(num, str);
printf("%s\n", str); // Output: "1234567890123456789"
```